# How do I put this title page in the horizontal centre using overleaf?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
   \vspace*{1cm}

   \textbf{Thesis Title}

   \vspace{0.5cm}
    Thesis Subtitle
        
   \vspace{1.5cm}

   \textbf{Author Name}

   \vfill
        
   A thesis presented for the degree of\\
   Doctor of Philosophy
        
   \vspace{0.8cm}
 
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{university}
        
   Department Name\\
   University Name\\
   Country\\
   Date
        
   \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be redefining `\maketitle` command as in the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
   \vspace*{1cm}

   \textbf{Thesis Title}

   \vspace{0.5cm}
    Thesis Subtitle
        
   \vspace{1.5cm}

   \textbf{Author Name}

   \vfill
        
   A thesis presented for the degree of\\
   Doctor of Philosophy
        
   \vspace{0.8cm}
 
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
        
   Department Name\\
   University Name\\
   Country\\
   Date
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you